# Sorting table column by id and field not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I use the following method in order to sort data (array) in a reusable Material datatable:

```
sortData(sortParameters: Sort) {
    const keyName = sortParameters.active;
    if (sortParameters.direction === 'asc') {
      this.tableData = this.tableData.sort((a, b) => a[keyName].localeCompare(b[keyName]));
    }
    else if (sortParameters.direction === 'desc') {
      this.tableData = this.tableData.sort((a, b) => b[keyName].localeCompare(a[keyName]));
    }
    else {
      this.getStudents();
    }
}
```

However, althought it works for `name` field, it does not work for `id` field. Another issue regarding to this method is that I want to ignore whitespaces of the `name` and want to use `trim()` method for the sorted values. It is working, but I think I have to find another solution that works for id columns also. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: what's the type of the value in id? is it also strings or something else?

Comment: @ChristianFritz They are integer, not string. The values like 1,2,3 (sequential id values).

Comment: Any idea regarding to sorting int and string values both?

Comment: well then there is your problem: numbers in JS don't have a localeCompare function. You'll need to implement a sort function that will make a case distinction based on `typeof a[keyName]`, or, better yet, have separate sort functions for each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use d3's ascending() and descending().

```
import {ascending, descending} from 'd3-array';

sortData(sortParameters: Sort) {
    const keyName = sortParameters.active;

    if (sortParameters.direction === 'asc') {
      this.tableData = this.tableData.sort((a, b) => 
    a_prop = a[keyName];
    b_prop = b[keyName];
    try {
      a_prop = a_prop.trim();
      b_prop = b_prop.trim();
    } catch (error) {
      //do nothing, must not have been a string
    }
ascending(a_prop, b_prop);
    }
    else if (sortParameters.direction === 'desc') {
descending(a_prop,b_prop);

      }
    else {
      this.getStudents();
    }
}
```

Alternative to importing D3.js, paste the code for the functions directly in your code since they are short.  Taken from
https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/ascending.js

```
ascending (a, b) {
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : a >= b ? 0 : NaN;
}
descending (a, b) {
    return b < a ? -1 : b > a ? 1 : b >= a ? 0 : NaN;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very nice and pretty solution. I make some little modification and post them. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`localeCompare` is a function of Strings, but if your other columns, like `id`, are not strings then you can't use it to sort them. You need separate sort functions for each type then. Here is one way to do this:

```js
const defaultSort = (a, b) => a < b;
const sortFunctions = {
  id: (a, b) => a < b,
  name: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b),
  // ....
};

function sortData(sortParameters: Sort) {
  const keyName = sortParameters.active;
  const sortFunction = sortFunctions[keyName] || defaultSort;
  if (sortParameters.direction === 'asc') {
    this.tableData = this.tableData.sort((a, b) => sortFunction(a, b));
  }
  else if (sortParameters.direction === 'desc') {
    this.tableData = this.tableData.sort((a, b) => sortFunction(b, a));
  } else {
    this.getStudents();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit it for TypeScript please? I could not fix some parts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually haven't learned typescript yet, but I always thought javascript is also valid typescript, meaning that type descriptors are optional. Is that not so? What is the error you are getting with my code?

Comment: Probably linting issues with the arguments to the sortFunctions (if I had to venture a guess). It should not prevent running unless very restrictive compiler options are configured.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I use @Katherine's solution by adding some modifications. But your answer is also helpful and I voted up ;)